# How to set JabRef to keep the bibtex key of imported duplicate bib item

Tags: jabref

JabRef version 2.10

I have two `.bib` files, they share some same items but with different BibTeX keys.

For example:

#### `references.bib`:

```
@Article{Anderson_1991,
  Title                    = {Discussion: The Kermack-McKendrick epidemic threshold theorem},
  Author                   = {Anderson, Roy M.},
  Journal                  = {Bulletin of Mathematical Biology},
  Year                     = {1991},

  Month                    = {Mar},
  Number                   = {1-2},
  Pages                    = {1-32},
  Volume                   = {53},
  Doi                      = {10.1007/BF02464422},
  Timestamp                = {2015.01.28}
}
```

#### `references2.bib`:

```
@Article{Anderson_Epidemic,
  Title                    = {Discussion: The Kermack-McKendrick epidemic threshold theorem},
  Author                   = {Anderson, Roy M.},
  Journal                  = {Bulletin of Mathematical Biology},
  Year                     = {1991},

  Month                    = {Mar},
  Number                   = {1-2},
  Pages                    = {1-32},
  Volume                   = {53},
  Doi                      = {10.1007/BF02464422},
  Timestamp                = {2015.01.28}
}
```

I used JabRef to import `references2.bib` into `references.bib`, and chose to allow duplicates. However, in the result bib file, the `bibtexkey` of the `.bib` item in `references2.bib` was changed from

> Anderson_Epidemic

to

> Anderson1991

Here is the screen shot:

[image]

How can I maintain the `bibtexkey` of `Anderson_Epidemic`?

I need to maintain the `bibtexkey` of `Anderson_1991` as well. Because they are both used in my LaTeX files. I am in the process of merging them, but I need to have these two keys together in a `.bib` file first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adjusting the import settings: Options > Preferences > BibTeX key generator. Now deselect the option "Generate keys for imported entries":

[image]

Comment: The option "Generate keys for imported entries" seems to be absent in the current version of Jabref

Answer (score 0):

In later versions of Jabref, select Options > Preferences > Import and Export (from the sidebar). Under General, deselect "Generate a new key for imported entries (overwriting their default)" and click Save.

(h/t to @Werner)